# Exclude retweets when scraping tweets from accounts using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of Twitter usernames and I use the following code to retrieve 100 tweets from each user:

```
account_list = list(['altgeldshrugged', 'colsonwhitehead', 
                     'NickKristof', 'ayeletw', 'Bourdain'])
data = []
for i in account_list:
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=i, count=100, include_rts=False)
    print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))
    for t in tweets:
        data.append(t.text)
newdata = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(100, 13), columns=account_list)
```

However, the 100 tweets per user include retweets. When I use filter 'include_rts=False', the result will be like:

```
Number of tweets extracted: 90.
Number of tweets extracted: 26.
Number of tweets extracted: 96.
Number of tweets extracted: 42.
Number of tweets extracted: 32.
```

How can I modify the script so I get 100 tweets excluding retweets?

Comment: The Twitter API call that tweepy is making doesn't support that. From the Twitter API docs: "When set to false, the timeline will strip any native retweets (though they will still count toward both the maximal length of the timeline and the slice selected by the count parameter)."